# Collection of list of integer changing number to access the different variable names

Tags: vb.net

```
Public p1 = New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
Public p2 = New List(Of Integer)({5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 10, 2, 11})
Public p3 = New List(Of Integer)({11, 8, 10, 9, 7, 12, 6, 13, 14, 15})
```

I want to display the list p depending on how much is A. if a is 1 then it will be p1, if a is 2 then it will be p2. how can i access the list using this loop without having to manually write the code so many times.

```
   For a As Integer = 1 To 20
                If strDigit(str) = a Then
                    If a = 1 Then
                        Dim astr As Integer = 0
                        For Each num In p1
                            astr = Val(astr) + 1
                            If num + 1 >= 1 AndAlso num + 1 <= 1000 Then
                                If pos < 5 Then

                                Else

                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    ElseIf a = 2 Then
                        For Each num In p2
                            Dim astr As Integer = 0
                            If num + 1 >= 1 AndAlso num + 1 <= 1000 Then
                                If pos < 5 Then

                                Else

                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                    ElseIf a = 3 Then
                        For Each num In p3
                            Dim astr As Integer = 0
                            astr = Val(astr) + 1
                            If num + 1 >= 1 AndAlso num + 1 <= 1000 Then
                                If pos < 5 Then

                                Else

                            End If
                        Next
```

This should normally be the case, but it doesn't work that way.

```
   For a As Integer = 1 To 20
                If strDigit(str) = a Then
                    If a = 1 Then ' remove line
                        Dim astr As Integer = 0
                        For Each num In p(a) ' here
                            astr = Val(astr) + 1
                            If num + 1 >= 1 AndAlso num + 1 <= 1000 Then
                                If pos < 5 Then

                                Else

                                End If
                            End If
                        Next
                      End If
```

Comment: All three lists contain 8, so what happens if `A` is 8? Try providing us with ALL the relevant information when asking a question, so we don't have to guess, assume or drag all the details out of you by asking questions that you should already have considered and answered.

Comment: will be written 8 => 3 times, it doesn't matter that a number can appear in multiple lists, if it were, I would most likely specify. I will try the Linq code in the hope that I will be able to implement it, also thanks for the help provided

Comment: You have clearly failed to provide a lot of relevant information in your question. Try again. This time, provide a FULL and CLEAR e4xplanation of the problem. As it is, you have asked how to access THE list containing a specific value so there's no answer to that question that involves writing anything, let alone three times. Don't expect us to read your mind or work what you want to do from code. Make the effort to explain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one with sorted list

```
  Dim slist As New SortedList(Of Integer, List(Of Integer))

            Dim p1 = New List(Of Integer)({1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10})
            slist.Add(1, p1)

            Dim p2 = New List(Of Integer)({5, 4, 6, 7, 3, 8, 9, 10, 2, 11})
            slist.Add(2, p2)
            Dim p3 = New List(Of Integer)({11, 8, 10, 9, 7, 12, 6, 13, 14, 15})
            slist.Add(3, p3)
            Dim p4 = New List(Of Integer)({9, 16, 2, 43, 12, 11, 21, 22, 23})
            slist.Add(4, p4)

            Dim tmpList As List(Of Integer)

            For Each a In slist.Keys
                If slist.ContainsKey(a) = True Then
                    tmpList = slist.Item(a)

                    For Each num In tmpList
                        astr = Val(astr) + 1
                        If num + 1 >= 1 AndAlso num + 1 <= 1000 Then
                            If pos < 5 Then

                            Else

                            End If
                        End If

                    Next

                End If


            Next
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ is a great way to make code that would normally involve a loop more succinct.

```vb
Dim lists = {p1, p2, p3}
Dim list = lists.First(Function(l) l.Contains(A))
```

If more than one list contains the specified number, that code will return the first one in which it is found, so that would depend on the order you search them.